# How can I determine the method of this DDoS attack?

Tags: ddos, swap

My server went down earlier - looks like a DDoS. A spike in traffic to around 13mbit, the swap goes from idle to maxed in about 5 minutes, and server stops responding.

I would like to protect against the attack but I can't determine the method. Server logs show no increased http connections or usage, nor mysql or mail usage above usual levels. Server graphs only show spikes in Network, I/O, and Memory Usage:

Memory Usage: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTnvZ.gif
IO Graph: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsLHj.gif

I can't fathom what type of attack this is. Where could this be targetting and how can I protect against it? All comments gratefully received.

Comment: See what netstat -n says.

Comment: Request logging? Software and site technologies? Any details??

Answer (score 0):

The spike in IO is likely your system trying to use all that swap. The first thing I would do is figure out what process is using all that swap. You may need to patch your `ps` in order to do this easily: http://r0bertz.blogspot.com/2010/04/show-real-swap-usage-for-each.html

Comment: Thank you - that's useful for the future. If not httpd, mysql, or mail, what process could a DDos cause to fork?

Answer (score 0):

SYN-Flodding?

If the DDoS came from a defined geographic region, ask your provider for blocking them.

Comment: SYN flooding seems like a possibility, but any way I can confirm? Obviously box is now rebooted so netstat isn't saying much, but box is running CentOS and Cpanel.